# DOM MILD Steel ASTM A513 Type 5 Tube

Tags: mechanical-engineering, materials, steel

How can the DOM MILD Steel ASTM A513 Type 5 Tube be improved for corrosion resistance.

it has a low but good welding and machinery ability but if we want to improved the material for corrosion resistance what element will we apply to it?

can we reduce carbon added to make it excellent welding ability and add more magnesium to make more corrosion resistance.?

or we can use Application of zinc coating – steel galvanization it’s a process which creates a coating of zinc over metals surface.

need more formal answer on this subject.

Comment: What is the environment causing the corrosion? Are you changing the production process of the tube or treating it after it has been produced?

Comment: i think applying it in the production process no changing the process. or doing that will alter production process.?

Comment: If you apply the change in the production process then that alters the process... And if you change the process it will then be a different grade.

Comment: @SolarMike what will be considering here is after the production process we apply the coating?
by the way we talking about the zinc coating here, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

- Yellow Chromating over zinc for white rust from moisture
- High Performance Passivation for red rust from salt spray

Comment: @ Tony can you elaborate more on the above two process.

Comment: It would easier for you to search my answers for an explanation or a supplier